# How to make xscales and xaxis from this data D3 V4

Tags: d3.js

I am working on D3 V4.

I have this data

```
 dataset = [{"Time": "33:10"},{"Time": "33:12"}]
```

How do I make scaleTime from this?

Also this approach is wrong:

```
var max = new Date(d3.max(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]}));
var min = new Date(d3.min(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]})); 


var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                       .domain([min,max])
                       .range([padding, width-padding]);
```

Since - it can't create correct Date object from this format:

```
 "33:12"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comments inline:

**For D3 V3** time parsing

```
 dataset = [{"Time": "33:10"},{"Time": "33:12"}]

//First convert your data to date object like this:
var myParser  = d3.time.format("%M:%S");
//run for loop and use parser to parse  the date.
dataset.forEach(function(d){ 
    d.Time = myParser.parse(d.Time);//now its a dateObject
})
//Now get your max and min from the date Object
var max = new Date(d3.max(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]}));
var min = new Date(d3.min(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]})); 


var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                       .domain([min,max])
                       .range([padding, width-padding]);
```

**For D3 V4** time parsing

```
 dataset = [{"Time": "33:10"},{"Time": "33:12"}]

//First convert your data to date object like this:
var myParser  = d3.timeParse("%M:%S");
//run for loop and use parser to parse  the date.
console.log(myParser)
dataset.forEach(function(d){ 
    d.Time = myParser(d.Time);//now its a dateObject
})
//Now get your max and min from the date Object
var max = new Date(d3.max(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]}));
var min = new Date(d3.min(dataset, function(d){return d["Time"]}));
```

Comment: Thank you! I did my own solution: just appending some constant string to the date string: new Date("Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:"+string);  - and now I realize it was really ugly.

Comment: How do you parse string into date object in version 4?

Comment: Edited my answer for V4.